# Google Maps Markers not appearing?

Tags: ajax, json, google-maps, jsonp, google-maps-markers

I am using the below code to GET a JSONP response and parse out the lat and long and output as Makers on a google map.

The console.out shows the correct lat and long in the console, however the Markers are not appearing on the map.

What am I doing wrong?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
    <style type="text/css">
      html { height: 100% }
      body { height: 100%; margin: 0; padding: 0 }
      #map_canvas { height: 100% }
    </style>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=true">
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      var map;
      function initialize() {
        var mapOptions = {
          center: new google.maps.LatLng(-36.8, 174.6),
          zoom: 12,
          mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        };
      }
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>    
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="map_canvas" style="width:100%; height:100%"></div>
    <script>
     $(document).ready(function() {
        jQuery.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: 'http://api.at.govt.nz/v1/public/realtime/vehiclelocations?api_key=<APIKEYHERE>',
            dataType: "jsonp",
            cache: false,
            crossDomain: true,
            processData: true,

            success: function (data) {
                //alert(JSON.stringify(data));
                var iconBase = 'images/';
                map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"),
            mapOptions);

                $.each(data.response.entity, function(key, data) {
                    var latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(data.vehicle.position.latitude,data.vehicle.position.longitude); 
                    console.log(latLng);
                    // Creating a marker and putting it on the map
                    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                        position: latLng,
                        map: map,
                        //icon: iconBase + 'bus2.png'
                    });
                });
              initialize();
            },
        error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
         alert("There is a problem");
        }

       });
     });
```

Comment: What does the data returned by the AJAX query look like?

Answer (score 1):

You create the map twice, in the ajax-callback and `onload`.

Remove the `onload`-listener and call `initialize()` in the ajax-callback instead of

```
map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"),
            mapOptions);
```

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't work. I have updated the code to your suggestions.

Comment: your updated code code still creates the map twice, before and after the `$.each`

Answer (score 0):

Could it be that your marker(s) are beyond the maps' current bounds? After adding new markers, you need to change the map centre or bounds manually, Google Maps won't do it for you.

Zoom level 12 is quite narrow, so it's definitely a possibility.